# etcd error executing admin/config command

Tags: etcd

I am trying to execute an etcd admin request and am getting unusual errors.

I execute the following command (in the COREOS [documentation](https://coreos.com/etcd/docs/0.4.7/etcd-api/#cluster-config)):

```
curl -L http://127.0.0.1:7001/v2/admin/config
```

and I get the following response:

```
404 page not found
```

Note:  I confirmed that is etcd working (as I can see other commands work perfectly well).

My configuration is as follows:

```
$ etcd --version

etcd Version: 2.3.0
Git SHA: 5e6eb7e
Go Version: go1.5.3
Go OS/Arch: darwin/amd64
```

Is there anything obvious that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This api(v2/admin/config) is already deprecated, but I can't find a new one which can replace it.

Maybe this api will give you some useful infomation:

```
curl -L http://127.0.0.1:4001/v2/stats/self
```

The lastest documentation of etcd is [here](https://coreos.com/etcd/docs/latest/).

In fact, a lot of commands in the doc you mentioned(actually it is the doc of version 0.4.7) are deprecated already:

```
curl -L http://127.0.0.1:7001/v2/admin/machines
```

is replaced by :

```
curl -L http://127.0.0.1:7001/members
```

or you can use

```
curl -L http://127.0.0.1:4001/v2/members
```

The default port 4001/7001 will be [deprecated](https://github.com/coreos/etcd#etcd-tcp-ports) too.